# How to create file paths to use in html inside .php loop

Tags: php, html, filesystems, href

I have a simple file base on my webpage, let's say `ProjectFolder` is the main folder, which contains completely all files.

The folder I want to access goes like this:

```
ProjectFolder/Movies/Movie1/cover/Movie1.jpg  
ProjectFolder/Movies/Movie1/movie/Movie1.mp4  

ProjectFolder/Movies/Movie2/cover/Movie2.jpg  
ProjectFolder/Movies/Movie2/movie/Movie2.mp4  

ProjectFolder/Movies/Movie3/cover/Movie3.jpg  
ProjectFolder/Movies/Movie3/movie/Movie3.mp4
```

And so on... 
Movie 1,2,3,4... etc folders can be uploaded manually, so I have to be able to show all of them, no matter the count (they are also with various names, Movie1,2,3 is just for example)

Using `php`, I made a loop that goes through all subfolders of the `ProjectFolder/Movie` folder and for each one of them, creates a portion of html code, in which I need to use:

1. Link to a video file, currently "Movies/Movie1/movie/Movie1.mp4"
2. Link to a video file, currently "Movies/Movie1/cover/Movie1.jpg"
3. Button, which goes to a page: "http://myproject.com/am/Movie1.php"

This is my php:

```
$i = 1;  
$path = "./Movies";  
$dir = new DirectoryIterator($path);  
foreach ($dir as $fileinfo)  
{  
   if ($fileinfo->isDir() && !$fileinfo->isDot())  
   {  
     //(html code)  
   }  
}
```

What php code should I replace the html "" parts from 1, 2 and 3?

Comment: Do you want to know how to produce the html for the 'button'?

Comment: @DominicSore What do you mean? I have the entire page, I just need to change the link, depending on the Movie name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

$dir = './Movies';
$directories = array();
$files_list  = array();
$files = scandir($dir);

foreach ($files as $file)
{
    if (($file != '.') && ($file != '..'))
    {
         if (is_dir($dir.'/'.$file))
         {
              $directories[]  = $file;
         }
    }
}

foreach ($directories as $directory)
{ 

?>
```

HTML code....

```
<?php echo "Movies/"; echo $directory; echo "/movie/"; echo $directory; echo ".mp4"; ?>
```

Same for ".jpg" and the button code looks like this:

```
<div>
   <form action="<?php echo "http://blabla.com/"; echo $directory; echo ".php"; ?>">
        <input type="submit" class="button" value="GO TO <?php echo $directory; ?>">
   </form>
</div>
```